# C++: Getters and Setters?

Tags: c++, file, class, getter-setter

I am attempting to write some code to create getters and setters for the ID number, first name, last name, midterm score, and final score of the following data, which is in a text file, in a class i'm writing...

```
10601   ANDRES HYUN 88 91 94 94 89 84 94 84 89 87 89 91 
10611   THU ZECHER 83 79 89 87 88 88 86 81 84 80 89 81 
10622   BEVERLEE WAMPOLE 95 92 91 96 99 97 99 89 94 96 90 97 
10630   TRUMAN SOVIE 68 73 77 76 72 71 72 77 67 68 72 75
```

The ID is the first number, first and last name are self explanatory, the midterm score is the second to last number, and the last number is the final score. This is my first time using getters and setters and so far I have...

```
int getID()const{return ID;}
void setID(int i) {ID=i}
string getFname()const{return Fname;}
void setFname(string f) {Fname = f}
string getLname()const{return Lname;}
void setLname(string l) {Lname = l}
int getMidterm()const{return Midterm;}
void setMidterm(int m) {Midterm=m}
int getFinal()const{return Final;}
void setFinal(int fl) {Final=fl}
```

Am I on the right track at all? Also, how do I specify that the first number in the data set is the ID, the first string is the first name, second string second name, second to last number is Midterm, and last number is final score?

Comment: Is your question about how to grab the input from a given text file and storing it into your class with those setter/getters? Is setting up those setter/getter a requirement?

Comment: looks good, but I'd past strings to your setters by const reference instead of by value (`string const &` instead of `string`)

Comment: Looks all good to me. You might want to use const references for strings.

Comment: "I am attempting to write some code to create getters and setters..." Stop right there -- it's already a poor idea.

Answer (score 5):

If you are asking about writing getters and setters, yes, this is how many people do it. To write "perfect" accessors to complex types, you would use this:

```
void setLname(const String& input) { Lname = input; }    //copies the string
void setLname(String&& input) { Lname = std::move(input); }    //moves the string
const String& getLname() const { return Lname; }    //allows to get a const String reference from a const object
String& getLname() { return Lname; }    //allows modifying access to Lname if the object is not const.
```

Note, that this is more than the two, people normally talk about, and usually only one getter and one setter are seen. Only very few people would want to write more than that. Yet, each of these four has a slightly different job to do and might be advisable to add.

However, lots of accessors are a code smell:

1. They litter the code with functions that do not provide *any* abstraction.
2. Whenever you have both a getter and a setter, you have essentially unrestricted access to that data member; so you could just as well have written `public: String Lname`.
3. Lots of accessors are a certain sign that you are modelling data, not behaviour. In those cases, you should either rethink your design, or be honest and go ahead and use either public members, or, if all members would be public, a `struct` IMHO.

Note, that I'm talking about the pure accessors here, not the ones, that actually do something sensible, like checking a value range, updating other members accordingly, and so on. And these pure ones are the ones you should avoid.

So, if I were you, I would ask myself: What *behaviour* do I need from my class? Do I really need to talk about all its data members in other code, or can I find sensible abstractions that my class can provide which would make the accessors useless? Is it possible that I'm thinking about modelling the wrong class of objects? Or do I really just want a container for my data that can be used and modified everywhere?

Comment: The first two accessors could also be written as `void setLname(String input) { Lname = std::move(input); }`. Note this could invoke one more move if move elision cannot be applied (like `x.setLname(std::move(some_lvalue))`).

Answer (score 1):

looks fine. some remarks:

- Pass `string` as `const string&` so you don't make a useless copy.
- More whitespace would help with readability
- Don't abbreviate things. `getFirstName()` is more readable than `getFname()`

As for your second question, you can use the many scanning/stream utilities available in C++, like `scanf`, `sscanf`, `fscanf`, `stringstream`, `iostream`, `fstream`, etc.

```
std::ifstream inFile("database.txt");
std::string line;
while (std::getline(inFile, line)) // for each line
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << line;

    int id;
    ss >> id;

    std::string firstName;
    ss >> firstName;

    // etc
}
```

Comment: Sure thing bob. `ifstream` is an "input file stream". it's for reading in files. `getline` reads one line from `inFile` and stores it in `line`, and returns `true` until the file is empty. streams in C++ allow you to read and write from different types using the`>>` and `<<` operators, so I convert `line` into a stringstream by writing `line` to the stream `ss`. Now I can freely extract data from the stream. `id << ss` extracts the first int from the stream and stores it in `id`. `firstName << ss` extracts one word from the stream and stores it in `firstName`.

Comment: There is no `operator <<` overload that allows calling it as you did above. Reading from a `std::stringstream` (or any other STL stream) is done with `operator >>`, and writing to the stream is done with `operator <<`. For both operator types the first parameter is the stream and the second is the value to be read/written to it. So in you example, reading an `int` is done with `ss >> id;`

Comment: You're totally right, I always mess that up. Thanks, I edited my post to reflect what you said.

Answer (score -1):

Part 1: 
That's exactly how getter and setter methods should look (at least in Java).

Part 2: 
To set the fields of the class you still have to parse the input manually.
I recommend looking into C++ iostreams, especially the [>> operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/) for input streams.